# Beam Angle vs Viewing Angle

Tags: led, infrared

I am looking at the product specs for an IR light and see that it has:

`Beam Angle: 50 deg`

`Viewing Angle: 25 deg`

What is the difference between viewing and beam angle?

[image]

[image]

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: If the beamis 50 degrees wide, you can be 25 degrees off axis and still see it. So I'm guessing viewing angle is the half angle. Be nice to know that's what the datasheet authors meant though.

Comment: @Brian, possibly but I am not sure that would really have to be given on the fact sheet. Here is the LED by the way http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Optek-TT-electronics/OP290A/?qs=sGAEpiMZZMsn8wIhgY8aVXtlLz3Xk6PYwOwAsX0I77g%3d

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't trust the summary specs given by the distributor. The real spec is what's in the original datasheet issued by the manufacturer.

AFAICT, the datasheet gives only an "emission angle" spec, with a typical radiant intensity vs angle curve on page 6:

[image]

Even the "typical" values and curves in the datasheet are not hard promises. Only the minimum and maximum value specs are actual promises from the manufacturer about the device performance.

Answer (score 3):

Beam angle is precisely the angle made between two vectors from source to the projection surface on the points where the intensity reduces to half on both sides.So, it is fixed for a given LED.

Viewing angle is the maximum angle at which a display can be viewed with acceptable visual performance. In a technical context, this angular range is called viewing cone defined by a multitude of viewing directions.